# OpenGL Line Drawing

Tags: opengl, line, glut

I am practicing the exercises from my textbook but I could not get the outputs that I should.

Here is what I have :

```
#include <math.h>
#include <GLUT/glut.h>
#include <OpenGL/OpenGL.h>

//Initialize OpenGL 
void init(void) {
    glClearColor(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0); 
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION); 
    gluOrtho2D(0.0,300.0,0.0,300.0);    
} 

void drawLines(void) {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);  
    glColor3f(0.0,0.4,0.2); 
    glPointSize(3.0);  

    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    glVertex2d(180, 15);
    glVertex2d(10, 145);
    glEnd();
} 

int main(int argc, char**argv) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);  
    glutInitWindowPosition(10,10); 
    glutInitWindowSize(500,500); 
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB); 

    glutCreateWindow("Example"); 
    init(); 
    glutDisplayFunc(drawLines); 
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

When I run this piece of code, I get completely blank white screen.

Comment: glut is not part of opengl, it is an extra library, so i have added that as a tag.

Comment: sorry for missing that. thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

i'm also not an expert on OpenGL but the problem is that you haven't set a viewport to where your scene should be projected. Your init should look somewhat like this:

```
glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);

glViewport(0, 0, 500, 500);

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();

glOrtho(0, 500, 0, 500, 1, -1);

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
```

You also need to put a glFlush(); after your drawing.

```
void drawLines(void) {
    ...
    glFlush();
}
```

Comment: I just saw that you also forgot to glFlush your rendering.

Comment: thx, glFlush solved my problem. please edit your post so I can accept your answer. (for others)

Answer (score -1):

Determine and draw the output of OpenGL sub function below:

1.

```c
glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);  
glBegin(Gl_LINES);  
glVertex2i (200, 200);  
glVertex2i (70, 20);  
glVertex2i (120, 150);  
glVertex2i (200, 20);  
glVertex2i (60, 100);  
glEnd();
```

2. 

```c
int p1[]={200,100};  
int p2[]={70,20};  
int p3[]={120,150};  
int p4[]={200,20};  
int p5[]={60,100};  
glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);  
glVertex2iv (p1);  
glVertex2iv (p2);  
glVertex2iv (p3);  
glVertex2iv (p4);  
glVertex2iv (p5);  
glEnd();
```

Comment: i want the solution for this